# json data sorting while printing

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

i send sorted hashmap data in `json` string form but while printing `json` data it not print as existing form.

`json` data is

```
{
    "409": "A T (C T)",
    "397": "A T (Government Model School)",
    "407": "A T (Junior)",
    "420": "A T (L T Adhoc Siksha Bandu)",
    "406": "A T (L T)",
    "408": "A T (Primary)",
    "500": "AT(JBT)",
    "402": "H M (High School)",
    "403": "H M (Junior)",
    "404": "H M (Primary)",
    "405": "Lecturer",
    "419": "Lecturer (Adhoc Siksha Bandu)",
    "401": "Principal",
    "398": "Siksha Acharya",
    "399": "Siksha Mitra"
}
```

while printing data is

[image]

my code for create dropdown is:

```
 $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {


                        $('#post_code').append(
                                $("<option></option>").text(value).val(key));
                    });
```

Comment: your code to create that dopdown?

Comment: it seems that while creating dropdown options the data is getting sort by value like 397, 398, 399 and so on. You need to sort it on label. please check that code.

Comment: my code to create drop down is   $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {


                            $('#post_code').append(
                                    $("<option></option>").text(value).val(key));
                        });

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like that in dropdown data is getting sorted by `key`(397,398,399...) instead of `value`.

JavaScript objects have no order. Even though most browsers do iterate in the same order the properties were created, there's `no guarantee`, so sorting is not supported on objects.

If you need a sort-able list, you'll have to store it as an array of objects:

```
var obj = [
    {key:"409", val:"A T (C T)"},
    {key:"397", val:"A T (Government Model School)"},
    {key:"407", val:"A T (Junior)"},
    {key:"420", val:"A T (L T Adhoc Siksha Bandu)"},
    {key:"406", val:"A T (L T)"},
    {key:"408", val:"A T (Primary)"},
    {key:"500", val:"AT(JBT)"},
    {key:"402", val:"H M (High School)"},
    {key:"403", val:"H M (Junior)"},
    {key:"404", val:"H M (Primary)"},
    {key:"405", val:"Lecturer"},
    {key:"419", val:"Lecturer (Adhoc Siksha Bandu)"},
    {key:"401", val:"Principal"},
    {key:"398", val:"Siksha Acharya"},
    {key:"399", val:"Siksha Mitra"}
];

$(document).ready(function() {
         $.each(obj,function(key,value)
         {
             var option = $('<option />').val(value.key).text(value.val);
        $("#dropDownDest").append(option);
         });
});
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Working fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/yhD9A/512/

Answer (score 0):

Your **responseJson** variable is an object.

**"An object is an unordered set of key/value pairs"**

The ordering of object is not guaranteed. Each execution may choose different ordering. Better save your data as **array**.